# How to refresh analytics:reportChart from Controller

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting, report-chart, analytics-reportchart

I have the following code in the visualforce page and a button so when the user clicks the button I would like to show the `reportChart` but its not happening

PS: Yes the reportId is not blank I'm debugging and also showing on the page and it does have reportId

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!getReportInfo}" value="Report Chart" reRender="op1"/>

<apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="op1" rendered="{!(!ISBLANK(reportId))}>    
  reportId: {!reportId} <br/>
  <analytics:reportChart reportId="{!reportId}" cacheResults="false"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference getReportInfo() 
{ 
   return null;
}
```

Comment: I even tried with `<apex:actionRegion` wrap with `apex:outputPanel` did not help that either.

Answer (score 0):

The `rerender` mechanism actually only affects child elements. It won't work if you try to `rerender` the same element that has the `rendered` property. Wrap it in another `outputPanel` and it should work:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="op1" layout="none">
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(reportId))}">
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: nope did not work